# MVC5 form not routing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this snippet of code;

```html
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "MyController")" method="post" >            
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="btnNext">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

But when the button is clicked it redirects to `http://<domain>:2024/MyController` and I get a http error

> 405.0 Directory listing is not allowed.

If I manually change the url to `http://<domain>:2024/MyController/Index` I get my page.

When I change the form code to the below it works.

```html
<form action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" method="post" >            
    ...
```

index method declaration is;

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
 {
  ...
 }
```

So it's an inconvenience, and this is the only place it happens. I can work round it by not using the Index action, but how can I track this down and fix it?

Comment: Can you share the declaration of your Index action with the HttpPost attribute in MyController?

Comment: See if http://serverfault.com/a/405585/56843 helps.

Comment: @GSerg That link refers to 403 errors, not 405?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, but it might be the same root cause (it's about how IIS handles extensionless URLs).

Comment: Do you have `Index` listed as the default value for `Action` in your route configuration?

Comment: This does sound like a routing issue. Can you post your routes?

Comment: Also, is Index decorated with a HttpGet or another filter which restricts it to GET requests only?

Comment: Fixed it. Turns out that somehow I had created a folder in the root of the application with the same name as my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking your routing rules, you can use the `Html.BeginForm` helper method to create forms properly.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName"), HttpMethod.Post)
{
//form controls
}
```